# How to call user defined function in Lambda .NET Syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

Ok, here's my problem. I have database table `BloodCenters`, which have `latitude` and `longitude` field. I want to query those table by using Linq Lambda Syntax by retrieving the BloodCenters which are inside the given radius relative to some point.

I am using this code, but it still give me error (inside the Where predicate):

```
public static List<BloodCenter> GetAllNearby(int latitude, int longitude, int radius, int limit){
    List<BloodCenter> res = null;
    res = new DBEntities().BloodCenters.Where(b =>
        Util.distance(latitude, longitude, b.Latitude, b.Longitude, "K") <= radius).Take(limit);
    return res;
}
```

Util.distance is a function returning a distance between 2 point of latitude and longitude.
**Edited**
So, I can't put my own function inside the Where predicate. But can I compute the distance using SQL Syntax? Here's my `Util.Distance` implementation:

```
public static double distance(double lat1, double longi1, double lat2, double longi2, string unit){
    var theta = longi1 - longi2;
    var dist = Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(lat1)) * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(lat2)) +
        Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(lat1)) * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(lat2)) * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(theta));
    dist = Math.Acos(dist);
    dist = RadianToDegree(dist);
    var miles = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    unit = unit.ToUpper();
    if (unit.Equals("K"))
        return miles * 1.609344;
    else if (unit.Equals("N"))
        return miles * 0.8684;
    else
        return miles;
}
```

Comment: Latitude and longitude as `int`'s?

Comment: you should try using sql server spatial data types instead of some managed code function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work because `Util.distance` is implemented in your C# code and the query surface has no idea how that would be translated to SQL (or even if that would be possible).

An immediate workaround is to fetch all records from the database and apply the predicate to instances, like this:

```
res = new DBEntities().BloodCenters.ToList()
          .Where(b => Util.distance(latitude, longitude, b.Latitude, b.Longitude, "K") <= radius)
          .Take(limit);
return res;
```

Of course fetching all the records isn't the best idea either, but sometimes there's simply no other way.

What you could try is to inline the logic of `Util.distance` inside the `Where` predicate. If the logic can be expressed using only "simple" operations (like basic math) the query surface would be able to translate it to SQL and everything would go smoothly.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) is a list of all methods that can be automatically translated to SQL.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Unfortunately I didn't see any trigonometry function on your link. I edited my question by giving the detail of `Util.Distance` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert `DBEntities().BloodCenters` to an `IEnumerable` or `List` or something else which is stored locally. Linq to SQL translates C# to SQL - and so you can use only functions which are provided by your SQL server.

An alternative is to simulate the function with translatable statements or to implement it at the database (stored procedure or like that)